# Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Unknown definition referenced in PRIMARY KEY

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am trying to create tables in Cassandra using JAVA API.

This query works perfectly and creates the table.

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TopQuery1(term text , "
            +"year text , "
            +"month text , "
            +"day text , "
            +"hour text , "
            +"count counter,"
            +"PRIMARY KEY (\"term\", \"year\", \"month\", \"day\", \"hour\" ));";
```

But when I execute the following query it throws an error.

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TopQuery2(term text , "
            +"year text , "
            +"month text , "
            +"day text , "
            +"hour text , "
            +"dayOfYear int , "
            +"weekOfYear int , "
            +"ProductCount int , "
            +"count counter,"
            +"PRIMARY KEY (\"term\", \"year\", \"month\", \"day\", \"hour\", \"dayOfYear\", \"weekOfYear\", \"ProductCount\"));";
```

This is the error :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Unknown definition dayOfYear referenced in PRIMARY KEY
at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:35)
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:289)
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:205)
at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:52)
at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:36)
at CreateTable.main(CreateTable.java:81)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Unknown definition dayOfYear referenced in PRIMARY KEY
at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:103)
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:140)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:293)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.onSet(RequestHandler.java:455)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.messageReceived(Connection.java:734)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateAwareChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(IdleStateAwareChannelUpstreamHandler.java:36)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.messageReceived(IdleStateHandler.java:294)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:70)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I seriously don't understand what I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column names are case-insensitive by default, unless you enclose them in double quotes.

When you define the column you don't use quotes, so it's called `dayofyear`:

```
+"dayOfYear int , "
```

But in your primary key definition you use quotes, so it's looking for a column called `dayOfYear`:

```
+"PRIMARY KEY (... \"dayOfYear\" ...)";
```

Either use quotes everywhere or nowhere (depending on whether case sensitivity matters).